# Better and cleanest way to bind a ICommand to a RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, clean-code

By reading various source code, I see that there is different ways of binding an ICommand to a RelayCommand :

- From the constructor

  ```
  MyAwesomeViewModel()  {
      this._fooCommand = new RelayCommand((x) => Bar(x)) 
  }
  ```
- Directly from the command property

  ```
  private ICommand _fooCommand ;
  public ICommand SearchCommand
  {
      get
      {
          return _fooCommand ?? (_fooCommand = new RelayCommand());
      }
  }
  ```

Which way is the better from your point of view ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat This question looks to me like a request for "best practices" and I think there's not much to add to the question.

Comment: @Em1 see **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: @gnat Well, first you didn't complain about this question being a "best practice" question in the first place but you asked for something which is not necessary here. For another, if I would've enough reputation on meta, I'd downvote the answer. I have a totally different view on this and you may be able to give some good reasons for why doing something in one way or the other. It's not a bad question per se.

Comment: @gnat The goal of my question here was to ask the community about the different possible options of declaring a command and what are the advantages and inconvenients of each method.
For example, is it a good practice to put some logic in the getter (like here in my second code snippet)
Which option seems the more readable ? I'm really careful about the readability of my code to allow another developer to understand my code fastly. Is there one method more testable than another ? Is there some performance differences from one method to another ?

Comment: see: [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: @gnat thanks it really helps me and also will really help people who came across this question searching for answers...

Comment: I generally go with the constructor one since I don't see the need for lazy loading a command.